# reflection nat / hairpin nat with iptables

Tags: iptables, nat

I try to implement reflection nat on one of my servers. There is a vm running on the server with ip 10.0.0.10.

My iptables look like this:

```
root@srv8:~# iptables -t nat -L -n -v --line-numbers
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 8 packets, 409 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      426 23387 DNAT       6    --  ens18  *      !10.0.2.0/24          0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:10.0.0.10:80
2     4796  285K DNAT       6    --  ens18  *      !10.0.2.0/24          0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 to:10.0.0.10:443
3       24  1080 DNAT       6    --  ens18  *      !10.0.2.0/24          0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000 to:10.0.0.10:3000
4        5   300 DNAT       6    --  vmbr0  *       10.0.0.10            xxx.212.198.74      tcp dpt:80 to:10.0.0.10:80
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 60 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 14 packets, 879 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 19 packets, 1176 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    58631 3639K ts-postrouting  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2      794 47640 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      ens18   10.0.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0           
3        0     0 SNAT       6    --  *      vmbr0   10.0.0.10            10.0.0.10            tcp dpt:80 to:100.212.198.74
Chain ts-postrouting (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1       25  1300 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            mark match 0x40000/0xff0000
```

As you can see, there are packets that hit the PREROUTING rule

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 8 packets, 409 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination      
4        5   300 DNAT       6    --  vmbr0  *       10.0.0.10            100.212.198.74      tcp dpt:80 to:10.0.0.10:80
```

But for any unkown reason, the POSTROUTING rule does not get hit.

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 19 packets, 1176 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination          
3        0     0 SNAT       6    --  *      vmbr0   10.0.0.10            10.0.0.10            tcp dpt:80 to:xxx.212.198.74
```

How can i debug this or where could the problem be?

Thanks in advance and yes, i have redacted the oublic ips to something random :)

EDIT: in the original version, the destination was 100.212.198.74 which implied to be a tailscale ip. This was missleading, cause this should represent just any public ip. i now edited it to be xxx.212.198.74 which should stand for a public ip. But yes, there is also tailscale running on the server.

Output of iptable-save -c: https://pastebin.com/raw/VLgYVTab

Comment: Could you show this part of the ruleset in `iptables-save -c` format? I see you're trying to NAT to a Tailscale address though, which presumably is available through a different interface; where is the "reflection/hairpin" then? (My guess is that Tailscale's _mangle_ rules are setting a packet mark and therefore causing your packets to hit the rule in ts-postrouting first, so they never reach the one you added.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
You are right, there is tailscale running on the server. 
I redacted the public IP a bit unfortunate... the 100.212.198.74 in in reality not a tailscale IP, its just the public web IP of the server. Therefore treat it as xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx public IP. 
Here is the output: https://pastebin.com/raw/VLgYVTab

Comment: Ah, right, that's indeed outside the Tailscale range that ends at 100.127. (One idea, add a `-j TRACE` rule for your packets to the 'raw' table, it should start logging to 'dmesg' every rule that the packet traverses...)

Comment: OK, i added the following: 
   iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j TRACE
If i check dmesg, there are no messages. but the DNAT Rule is upcounting: 
4      229 13740 DNAT       6    --  vmbr0  *       10.0.0.10            xxx.212.198.xxx tcp dpt:80 to:10.0.0.10:80

Comment: Any ideas from the community?

Comment: Can you post the output of the `iptables-save` command? Feel free to search & replace possibly sensitive public IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess this is the right one right? https://pastebin.com/raw/VLgYVTab

Comment: It seems to be a far more complex problem than i thought initially 

Comment: Any ideas from your side? Do you see any mistakes?